# Precise whole number calculation with double

Tags: c#, double, precision, biginteger

Consider following:

```
double x = 87974894654657d;
double y = 76216354532345d;
double a = x * y;
Console.WriteLine(a.ToString("n0"));

BigInteger x1 = new BigInteger(87974894654657);
BigInteger y1 = new BigInteger(76216354532345);
BigInteger a1 = x1 * y1;
Console.WriteLine(a1.ToString("n0"));
```

Output:

```
6.705.125.760.945.040.000.000.000.000
6.705.125.760.945.040.955.511.380.665
```

Is there a way to let `double` calculate the result properly? BigIntegers work fine, but are much slower than the floating point types. I'm using double instead of long because I'm working with extremely large numbers.

Comment: Only whole numbers up to 2^53 can be accurately stored in a double.

Comment: double precision is `16` digits. so you will loose numbers after that as number gets bigger. _Is there a way to let double calculate the result properly?_  No. There is no way with using single double because its 64 bits and you cant store more data than that. `BigIntegers work fine, but are much slower`  **You want precision. you must pay for it.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the output you are looking for (with "extremely large numbers") you will be constrained to use either BigInteger or decimal types.

```
double x = 87974894654657d;
double y = 76216354532345d;
double a = x * y;
a.Dump();


decimal xd = 87974894654657m;
decimal yd = 76216354532345m;
decimal b = xd * yd;
b.Dump();
```

Output:

```
6.70512576094504E+27
6705125760945040955511380665
```

Comment: Extremely large integers can only be handled by BigIntegers. Decimals only have 96 bits of precision, which is more than the usual hardware supported floating point types can handle, but it is not extremely large, IMO. Here, decimals are indeed large enough.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis Agreed -- the meaning of "extremely large" is not defined in the question, but seems to keep getting bigger as I age :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
        double d = 6705125760945040955511380665d;
        Console.WriteLine(d.ToString("n0"));
```

The output will be `6.705.125.760.945.040.000.000.000.000`. A double can represent very large values, but it cannot do it precisely. That's because it uses an exponent, a bit like adding 10^n. If you used decimals instead of binary numbers and used 4 digits you could store the number 5000000 like this: `05|06` => `5*10^6`. The largest number you can store this way is `99|99` => `99 * 10 ^ 99`, which is a huge number. But you cannot accurately store the number 123456, you can only approximate it: `12|04` => `120000`.

If you want precision, don't use floating point numbers like `float` or `double`, use `decimal` or `BigInteger` instead.

Comment: It isn't because it uses an exponent, it is because it has a fixed finite number of bits to store the number in. The exponent comes into play when describing the range of values you can store, but the number of precise digits is limited by the number of bits in the type. BigInteger and similar types have potentially unlimited number of bits at their disposal, at the cost of performance.

Comment: To clarify what I meant, the exponent is the reason it can store huge numbers in a small (fixed) amount of bits, but numbers stored this way are not always accurate.

Comment: Actually, `decimal` is a floating point too (96-bit mantissa, 8-bit exponent), the only difference is that the exponent is actually decimal and not binary, avoiding the precision errors of e.g. `0.1` in `double`. It will still only be precise "only" up to 96bits (~28.9 digits).

Answer (score 0):

Just executed

```
     Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.Second+" "+DateTime.Now.Millisecond+"");
     BigInteger x1 = new BigInteger(87974894654657);
   BigInteger y1 = new BigInteger(76216354532345);
   BigInteger a1 = x1 * y1;
  Console.WriteLine(a1.ToString("n0"));
    Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.Second+" "+DateTime.Now.Millisecond+"");

    Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.Second+" "+DateTime.Now.Millisecond+"");
    double x = 87974894654657d;
  double y = 76216354532345d;
  double a = x * y;
   Console.WriteLine(a.ToString("n0"));
    Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.Second+" "+DateTime.Now.Millisecond+"");
```

and got this result:

4 216

6,705,125,760,945,040,955,511,380,665

4 216

4 216

6,705,125,760,945,040,000,000,000,000

4 216

There wasn't a delay of even 1 millisecond.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the decimal type is a little bit faster than the BigInteger type.

```
        Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();

        stopwatch.Restart();
        double x = 87974894654657d;
        double y = 76216354532345d;
        double a = x * y;
        stopwatch.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine(a.ToString("n0") + " (" + stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds.ToString("0.000") + "ms)");

        stopwatch.Restart();
        BigInteger x1 = new BigInteger(87974894654657);
        BigInteger y1 = new BigInteger(76216354532345);
        BigInteger a1 = x1 * y1;
        stopwatch.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine(a1.ToString("n0") + " (" + stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds.ToString("0.000") + "ms)");

        stopwatch.Restart();
        decimal x2 = 87974894654657M;
        decimal y2 = 76216354532345M;
        decimal a2 = x2 * y2;
        stopwatch.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine(a2.ToString("n0") + " (" + stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds.ToString("0.000") + "ms)");
```

And here the output:

6.705.125.760.945.040.000.000.000.000 (0,002ms)

6.705.125.760.945.040.955.511.380.665 (0,044ms)

6.705.125.760.945.040.955.511.380.665 (0,030ms)

**UPDATE:**

With an iteration of 10 million the performance between the data types is even better seen:

double:     6.705.125.760.945.040.000.000.000.000 (24,558ms)

BigInteger: 6.705.125.760.945.040.955.511.380.665 (1623,420ms)

decimal:    6.705.125.760.945.040.955.511.380.665 (478,333ms)